# Проверка на вызов(new.target)

Tags: javascript

```js
function User(name,age){

if(!new.target){
return new User(name); //Автоматически за нас добавляет оператор new к аргументу name.  
} 

this.name = name;

if(!new.target){
return new User(age); // По идее она тоже должна вместо нас добавить оператор new к age, 
}                    //  но результат undefined. Помогите найти мой косяк(((

this.age = age;   
}


let call = User('Коля', 32);
alert(call.name);
alert(call.age);
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Уже нашел решение.
Вот что паника с людьми делает(((

```js
function User(name,age){

if(!new.target){
return new User(name,age);  
} 

this.name = name;
this.age = age;   
}

let call = User('Коля', 32);
alert(call.name);
alert(call.age);
```